# How do I handle CORS preflight in Azure Functions API (Python)?

Tags: python, function, azure, cors, http-headers

I am trying to make a POST on an Azure Function I deployed to retrieve JSON data. I get a CORS error.

**Access to fetch at '{API URL}' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

My front end sends the POST request with javascript:

```
    const data = { name: "jennifer" };

    const response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "http://localhost:3000",
            'Origin': 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
    })
```

and my back end handles the CORS preflight with:

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://localhost:3000",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, POST, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Origin, Content-Type, Accept"}

    #handle CORS preflight
    if req.method == "OPTIONS":
        return func.HttpResponse(headers=headers)
```

Did I handle the preflight incorrectly?

Comment: you can enable CORS from the portal directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors

Comment: I "solved" this by migrating from a consumption plan to an app service plan. This allowed me to add CORS into their fancy UI

Comment: @ErikaLu, please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you want to stay on Azure Functions' consumption plan, you can use Azure API Management consumption tier in front of your function app to add a CORS policy.

Comment: You can enable CORS on a consumption plan so this does not make sense

Comment: You're currently not able to set CORS on a Linux Consumption Plan - this is a known limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by migrating from a consumption plan to an app service plan. This allowed me to configure CORS with their fancy UI .

@AnthonyChu suggested

> If you want to stay on Azure Functions' consumption plan, you can use
>   Azure API Management consumption tier in front of your function app to
>   add a CORS policy."